# Fetch API how to get response body in catch?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I got the response from server like this:

```
Request URL:http://api.bfexchange.net/wallet/balance
Request Method:GET
Status Code:504 Gateway Time-out
Remote Address:52.78.140.154:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

But printing err in catch of fetch API just returns Error object.

```
fetch(...)
.then(...)
.catch((err) => {
    console.dir(err);
});
```

It prints this(from Google Chrome):

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    message: "Failed to fetch"
    stack: "TypeError: Failed to fetch"
    __proto__: Error
index.js:82
```

I want to get status code to proper error handling, like server is not responding like something.

Is there a way to get response data in this case? Else, what alternatives can I attempt?

Any advice will very appreciate it!

Comment: Hey , I am facing the same problem. When i execute request through postman then i get 404 as response. However fetch doesn't show status or code , it only gives an error ' Failed to fetch'. Could you guide me in this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the server uses CORS you will get the 5xx response, but it won't be as a rejection; the promise will be resolved with the response. If the server does not use CORS, you won't ever see a response and the promise will always be rejected (unless you use "no-cors", in which case you can get an opaque response that is useful in some service worker scenarios).